# how to make this code work for multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

```
foreach (TextBox c in this.Controls)
{
    foreach (Label lb in this.Controls)
    {   
        if (c.Text == string.Empty)
            c.Visible = false;
        else
        {
            c.Visible = true;
            if (c.Visible == lb.Visible)
                lb.Visible = true;
            else
                lb.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to do it in one loop for both TextBox and Label controls?

Comment: There is no relationship between your TextBoxes and your Labels.  Your code is silly from top to bottom.

Comment: That approach is extremely fragile.  Specifying a Type (Label lb) does not mean controls will only return lables, you need to use Controls.TypeOf() for that.  Next, the code assumes order of the labels and textboxes returned will have some relation to each other.  Best to create a List with that relation and work from that.